# Jquery - Check all checkboxes on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I know this may seem like an amateur problem but I am having trouble selecting all the checkboxes on page load using Jquery.  I figured it out with pure JS.

Also, once that problem is solved I need to iterate through all checkboxes and see if they are all checked.  If they are, alert the user they are all selected, if not all of them are selected then alert the user another message.

I have put together a simple Jsfiddle to help get started.  Any help would be appreciated.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/r8LRW/2/)**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Days of Week</th>
        <td>
        <div class="checkbox-group" id="checkboxes">
             <ul>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mon"/>
                <label for="mon">MON</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tue"/>
                <label for="tue">TUE</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wed"/>
                <label for="wed">WED</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="thur"/>
                <label for="thur">THUR</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="fri"/>
                <label for="fri">FRI</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sat"/>
                <label for="sat">SAT</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sun"/>
                <label for="sun">SUN</label>
             </li>
             </ul>              
            </div>
 <span id="allChecked" style="display:block; width:425px; text-align:center; color:#999999;">
                (all days selected)
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Uh, can't you just add a `checked` attribute to the input elements themselves? You don't need JS for that part and it's the correct way.

Comment: If you select all of them on page load, then why do you need to check if they're selected? I see no need for any JS at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var checkboxes = $( ':checkbox' );

    // Check all checkboxes
    checkboxes.prop( 'checked', true );

    // Check if they are all checked and alert a message
    // or, if not, alert something else.
    if ( checkboxes.filter( ':checked' ).length == checkboxes.length )
        alert( 'All Checked' );
    else
        alert( 'Not All Checked' );
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r8LRW/6/)

or if you want to update the `span`:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var checkboxes = $( ':checkbox' ),
        span       = $( '#allChecked' );

    checkboxes.prop( 'checked', true );

    checkboxes.on( 'change', function(){
        var checked = checkboxes.filter( ':checked' );
        if ( checked.length == checkboxes.length )
            span.text( '(All Days Selected)' );
        else
        {
            var days = jQuery.map( checked, function(n){return n.id;} );
            span.text( '(' + days.join(', ') + ' Selected)' );
        }
    } );
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r8LRW/7/)

Comment: MTO, Thank you so much! This works perfectly.  I like how you created an array and called back the days that were checked.  Very clever! You answered my question and beyond. Props to you!

Answer (score 3):

To check them all

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
```

to see if they are all checked (seems you have to set the attribute for the custom styling)

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').length === $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8LRW/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
});
```

I just tried it in your JSFiddle link and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link below that shows various ways to achieve the same:

[Check all checkboxes on page load with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126736/check-all-checkboxes-on-page-load-with-jquery)

Hope this helps.
Thanks,
Jatin

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('[type=checkbox]').attr({'checked':'checked'});

var checkedArray = [] ; 
$.each($('[type= checkbox]'),function(index,value){
    if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
    checkedArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
    console.log(checkedArray.length);
    //["mon", "tue", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat", "sun"] 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/r8LRW/5/)

`checkedArray` array will have a list of `id` of the checked checkbox

And you can do `checkedArray.length` to get the array length